# how to change the format of the return value of 'mnist.load_data()' to 'mnist_train.csv' in Keras?

Tags: numpy, keras, mnist

I use Keras.

```
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

X_train' shape is `(number_of_training_sample,224,224,3)`

Y_train's shape is `(number_of_training_sample, 10)`

Features and labels are separated in different ndarray.
BUT I want to change these ndarrays to 'mnist_train.csv' format.
(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sjwhitworth/golearn/master/examples/datasets/mnist_train.csv)

My own dataset is totally same format with the return value of 'mnist.load_data()'. BUT only 'mnist_train.csv' format is worked in the code that I want to use.

Could you let me know how to change the format????
(Sorry for really simple question.. I am a newbie of numpy and python.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

loads data as numpy arrays

'mnist_train.csv' is a .csv file store on a hard disc which we usually read with pandas library

```
import pandas as pd
X_train = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
```

Pandas reads a .csv as a dataframe (with column names if there are such)
Using keras you need numpy arrays, so the

```
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

should work fine

Post the code you are using and the errors that is produced for further explaination

Comment: My own dataset's format is same with the return value of mnist.load_data(). I just want to change  the 2 ndarray (x_train, y_train) to one csv file with the same format of 'mnist.csv'

Comment: (x_train, y_train),(x_test,y_test) = myownData.load_data(). I want to make 'train.csv' with 2 ndarrays(x_train + y_train)