# CNN predictions work from test set but not own images

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

Im trying to do a CNN gender classifier and it works fine with images from the test set but when I input iamges from google its always classifying as male. I tried getting the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54519303/keras-mnist-test-own-images-bad-prediction) but it didnt solve it.

```
data = pd.read_csv('/content/age_gender.csv')

## Converting pixels into numpy array
data['pixels']=data['pixels'].apply(lambda x:  np.array(x.split(), dtype="float32"))

classification = ['Male', 'Female']

X = np.array(data['pixels'].tolist())

## Converting pixels from 1D to 3D
X = X.reshape(X.shape[0],48,48,1)
X = X / 255.0

y = data['gender'].values

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.22, random_state=37)

model = Sequential.....   # create the CNN and compile it
history = model.fit.....          # fit the model and evaluate it gives me val_accuracy: 0.8902
```

Test loss: 0.24722696840763092
Test Accuracy: 0.8912960290908813

When I predict an image from the test set using the following code it works fine.

```
index = 5009
image = X_test[index]

pred = model.predict(image.reshape(1, 48, 48, 1), batch_size=1)

print(classification[pred.argmax()])
```

But when I try to predict images from google it always comes back as male.

```
file = "/content/female-2.jpeg"
image = cv.imread(file, cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

image = cv.resize(image, (48, 48))
image = image.reshape(1, 48, 48, 1)
image = image.astype('float32')
image = 255-image
image /= 255

pred = model.predict(image.reshape(1, 48, 48, 1), batch_size=1)
print(classification[pred.argmax()])
```

I have tried a whole bunch of different images that are females and it ALWAYS comes back as male. What am I missing here?

Comment: It could be because you trained the model on grayscale images.

Comment: But I'm converting the images that I input to grayscale? Shouldn't that be ok?

Comment: Color does have important features for this use case. For your current model could you plot the ROC and AUC, to see well it does when it comes to false positive.

Comment: I just noticed this but you preprocess the images from google differently. You minus 255 from the image then you divide by 255.  Instead try just dividing it by  `255.0`. It needs to be a floating point number as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You preprocess the images from Google differently compared to when you train the model. The normalization of the pixel values is what causes the issue.

```
image = 255-image
image /= 255
```

This should instead be:

```
image /= 255.0
```